# What is the importance of association multiplicity in class diagrams?

Tags: associations, class-diagram, multiplicity

What is the importance of association multiplicity in class diagrams?
Why and when should we indicate them?
Thanks.

Comment: @burnt_hand: I don't think so. It's very easy to forget these things in a rush because the designer thinks those multiplicities are known to everybody anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They allow the designer a quick visual way of communication that would be difficult without multiplicities. You would have to use notes or other space-eating annotations in the diagram.

In a UML diagram I want to have multiplicities for all other associations other than one-on-one.

Why?

- One-on-one is the visual cue you get from a simple association. It's sort of the default.
- Multiplicities contain domain knowledge (car->wheel is usually a 1 -> 4 association. The association **without** the multiplicity looks like a car has **one** wheel.
- A designer can "deserialize" the things he thinks are granted because everybody **in the domain** probably knows them, but the developer probably does **not** know!

Answer (score 1):

They convey the business rules more directly. E.g an house contains one or more rooms.

Answer (score 1):

UML gets used in many ways. There are a huge number of things a class diagram could show. If you're trying to exhaustively document a system's design then you *may* need to show them all. If you're trying to explain a more specific aspect of the design, only show it if it's relevant (i.e. has a bearing on how that aspect would be designed/implemented).